# Continuous Markov Chains: long-run time

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

I'm looking for a walkthrough of how to do this problem.  Thank you in advance!

> Q: The best parking spot in town is known only to Uber and Lyft taxi drivers. We
>   assume that the taxi drivers arrive to the parking spot according to a Poisson process
>   with rate 4 per hour. Among these 60% are Uber drivers. An Uber driver stays at the
>   parking spot for an exponential random time (in hours) with parameter 3 and a Lyft
>   driver stays for an exponential random time with parameter 2. A driver can park at
>   the spot only if no other taxi is parked there. What is the long-run fraction of time
>   during which the parking spot is occupied by a Lyft driver?

Comment: Do drivers wait to park in an occupied spot, i.e. forming a queue?

Comment: @AlexR. I don't think so; this is all the information that is given